# Delphi rest client does not display special characters

Tags: delphi, rest-client

I am working with the rest client components and have noticed they do not seem to display special characters correctly. For example, the star character **`☆`** is displayed as a question mark **`?`** and I was hoping that there might be an easy solution to fix this issue and would be grateful for any advise.

By request, I have added more information to my original post in an attempt to make things more clear.

Here is what I am doing.

1.) I place `TRestClient`, `TRestRequest`, and `TRestResponse` components on my form and link them together in the object inspector at designtime.

2.) I then add the url I want to query to the TRestClient's `BaseURL` property at design time.

3.) Finally, I right click on the TRestRequest component on my form and click on the `Execute...` action.

Doing the above will query the BaseURL I entered in the TRestClients BaseURL property and the response to the query is handed over to the TRestRequest component which processes the request and then provides the result of the request to the TRestResponse component which has a read only property called "Content" which holds the response from the server and it can be viewed by holding holding your mouse over it in the object inspector at design time.

The original JSON structure (which is encoded as 1252 ANSI - Latin I) that appears in my web browser (FireFox) looks something like this:

```
{
    "id" : 17,
    "title" : "Shooting Star â˜†",
    "episodes" : 13
]
```

When I change the page encoding in Firefox to "Unicode" the structure then looks like this

```
{
    "id" : 17,
    "title" : "Shooting Star ☆",
    "episodes" : 13
]
```

When I look at the response in the object inspector however the `☆` character in the "Shooting Star ☆" entry is converted into a question mark `?`character and I would like for it to be "**displayed**" as it appears in my browser when the page mode is set to Unicode.

I have managed to do this against the original string using the UTF8ToUnicodeString function, but this is only possible if the orginal string is untouched, but the RestClient does not preserve these characters and instead converts them to question mark `?` symbols.

I guess the question I should be asking in this case is how to tell the "offending component" to not convert these characters in the first place?

Comment: "Display" where exactly?  Please be more specific, and show an actual example of what you are doing.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have updated my original post with more information. I hope this clears up any confusion you may have had.

Comment: This is because the Object Inspector's font doesn't contain that particular code point. Since you can't change the OI font, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: I agree with Ken.  If you actually run the code and then display the `Content`, such as in a MessageBox or UI control, does the star appear correctly?

Comment: No. The ? indicates text encoding conversion failure. Missing glyph would be a square symbol.

Comment: @user How are you dealing with text encoding?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not doing anything special with the text encoding. I am simply using the defaults that the components use. The same behaviour can been seen using the Rest Debugger program that ships with Delphi. I do agree it is an encoding problem, but I lack the specific knowledge on how to fix it.

Comment: I've no idea how to fix it either. All I'm saying is that it looks like a text encoding/conversion problem rather than a missing glyph. That's all I have to offer.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I did a test and discovered the original string was encoded as **1252 (ANSI - Latin I)** if that matters for anyone that may have an idea on how to fix this problem.

Comment: There is no way that the original text is 1252 encoded - that codepage does not contain a star character like the one in your post.  The original text is probably unicode but is sending a bogus encoding header.

Comment: @J...  I have updated the original question to correct the JSON code that shows in the browser before changing the page encoding type to Unicode. I do not really think any of this matters however, because the problem really is that the one of the REST components are converting the original string that appears on the server to display question marks in place of the original characters and I need to know how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: The file that you think is 1252 encoded is UTF-8. You aren't going to make any progress at all until you get on top of encodings.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The reason I said the original string was 1252 encoded is because that is what delphi reports back to me when I check for the encoding type when I placed the original code in a memo component, but that could very well be the memos encoding and not the encoding of the original string so I see your point. As far as getting on top of the encodings, that is exactly what I thought I was trying to ask in my original question. I am not sure what code I need to change in the REST components that will affect the encoding, which is why I am asking for help.

Comment: I don't know anything about REST. All I can tell you is that you have problems with your encodings.